# Placeholder of textarea not visible when moved outside of the textarea

Tags: html, css

I have been following this [small tutorial](http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-material-design-floating-input-placeholder/) to add an animation to the placeholder of an input-field. The animation moves the placeholder out of the input-field when the input-field is focused.

This animation works perfectly on an input-field, and the placeholder is visible above the input-field, but when i add this animation to a textarea, the placeholder disappears once it passes the edge of the textarea.

```css
 input,
textarea {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
 transform: translateY(-20px);
 visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="edit-field-name-0-value" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="Name *" required="required">
<textarea rows="8" cols="60" placeholder="Message *" required="required"></textarea>
```

Here's an [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b372a8ja/) to demonstrate the problem.

Does anyone have an idea how i can also show the placeholder of the textarea above it?

Comment: Your placeholder will disappear once somebody types something in so it is not a replacement for a `label`. Otherwise I would guess it's the textarea's overflow that's causing you bother. But it might be better to try to use `label`s. You could move them over your textarea that has no placeholder by using the transform property.

Comment: Ditto @somethinghere. A better way is actually to vertically offset a label so that it appears in the input/textarea, and then move it back when the element is in focus. This can easily be done in CSS, as long as your label element is after the input/textarea (for the adjacent sibling selector `+` to work)

Comment: @Terry I would use the transform property to offset it vertically, (so you could do something like `transform: translate(calc(1em + 10px))` (assuming 10px is your padding or something). Transform leaves the elements original space intact, so thats why I suggested it :) (no annoying refitting of boxes)

Comment: @somethinghere If you use position: relative, that would work, too, but tweening cardinal positions (e.g. `top`) does not support sub pixel value, while CSS transform does ;) I've updated my answer to include using CSS transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [@somethinghere's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464984/placeholder-of-textarea-not-visible-when-moved-outside-of-the-textarea#comment70135680_41464984), you will run into an accessibility/usability issue when the input fields are non-empty, which removes the placeholder. Although somewhat different than your original approach, using a combination of CSS positioning, HTML labels and flexbox allows you to achieve the same effect, without losing indicators of each field when they are filled.

The approach is simple:

- Wrap input and label elements in `<div>` elements. Labels have to appear **after** the inputs for the adjacent sibling selector `+` to work
- Use flexbox to position the label before the input, by reversing the column direction, using `flex-direction: column-reverse`. The advantage of this approach is that you can reorder the elements as you like, such as on mobile screens and etc.
- Use `+` to move the labels by changing their `top` property when the accompanying input/textarea is in focus

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 1em;
}
label {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: .35em;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
input:focus + label,
textarea:focus + label {
  top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="edit-field-name-0-value" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="Name *" required="required">
  <label for="edit-field-name-0-value">Name *</label>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea rows="8" cols="60" placeholder="Message *" required="required" id="textarea0"></textarea>
  <label for="textarea0">Message *</label>
</div>
```

---

If you want to use CSS transforms instead of `top` positioning, that is also possible:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 1em;
}
label {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(1.5em);
  left: .35em;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
input:focus + label,
textarea:focus + label {
  transform: translateY(0);
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="edit-field-name-0-value" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="Name *" required="required">
  <label for="edit-field-name-0-value">Name *</label>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea rows="8" cols="60" placeholder="Message *" required="required" id="textarea0"></textarea>
  <label for="textarea0">Message *</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This really is the most accessible and semantically thought out way to do it. Users with no CSS still get labels, even after they typed text. Nobody loses, everybody wins. +1

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go with this solution, since the placeholder (or label in the my new case) remains visible once the user starts typing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the browser hides the placeholder text of a `<textarea>`. An easy way to circumvent this behavior is to give the `textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder` element a `position: absolute;`. *This, however, has the drawback, that you cannot position it correctly.*

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  position: absolute;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
 transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="edit-field-name-0-value" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="Name *" required="required">
</div>
<div>
  <textarea rows="8" cols="60" placeholder="Message *" required="required"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm viewing your code snippet on OS X Safari, and the placeholder text remains hidden.

Comment: The textarea placeholder in safari is in the top left corner, nowhere near the textarea.

Comment: @somethinghere It was just the correct hint, how to make it visible outside of the `<textarea/>`. Of course you need a wrapper to position it correctly. I changed it, so that it is also at the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround, you'll have to add a wrapper tag and also add the below style:

```
.textarea-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b372a8ja/4/)

*Screenshot:*

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
input,
textarea {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
 transform: translateY(-20px);
 visibility: visible !important;
 position: absolute;
}
```

You just need to add position as absolute when the placeholder is focussed

Answer (score 0):

BTW I'm create simply CSS:

```
input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    transition: transform .3s ease-out;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
input.form-control:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    transform: translateY(-10px) scale(0.8);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

For exmpl, like here http://www.rusfond-finans.ru/loans/orderzaim.phtml